# Order in which processes will be carried out

Tags: c, process, minix

I'm fairly new to C, so I apologize if this is a simple question. I'm writing a C program, part of which is below. The goal of the overall program is to copy a file from one location to another (files are passed as arguments, with the final argument being the destination). `main()`, below, uses `fork()` to create one child process for each file passed, and I need to print out the file name (just the input argument) along with a message that may include the PID for each copy attempt after all child processes have run.

I can obviously get and use the PID, that's not a problem, but how can I get the right file name/argument that's tied to that process? The method I have in there now is obviously wrong; simply iterating through each argument in order won't be correct. This will be run on Minix 2.0.4, but I don't know if that matters.

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i, pid, rem, status;
   int pids[argc];
   char cfstatus[];

   rem = argc;

   for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      if((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error while forking");
      }
      else if(pids[i] == 0) {
         if(copyfile(argv[i], argv[argc - 1]) == 1)
            exit(4);
         else
            exit(0);
      }
   }

   i = 0;

   while(rem > 1) {
      pid = wait(&status);
      cfstatus = getcfstatus(status, pid);
      printf("%-20s: %s", argv[i], cfstatus);
      rem--;
      i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: the code should check that argc is (at least) 3 and if that test fails, output a error message indicating the correct format and then exit

Comment: argc include a count for the name of the program (that name is found at argv[0])) so the code needs to be modified to take those two details into account

Comment: Ah, okay. It does check for the number of arguments and fails if too few are passed, but I removed that check in the interest of keeping the code snippet to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, the child process whose PID is stored in `pids[i]` will operate on the file named by `argv[i]`.  There's no uncertainty whatsoever about that.  `i` is duplicated along with everything else by the `fork` operation, and not modified thereafter.

However, because all the children run in parallel, they may *complete* in any order.  That is, each call to `wait` might return any of the PIDs in the array (that hasn't already been returned).  So what you need to do in your `wait` loop is map *back* from the pid value returned by `wait`, to its index in the `pids` array, and then you know the right index in `argv` to print out.  For a program like this, a linear search through the array is probably good enough.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

this line (other than 'i' must not be 0) has a few problems

```
"if(copyfile(argv[i], argv[argc - 1]) == 1)'
```

if the command line is:
programname srcFile desFile

then argc = 3
then argv[argc-1]  = srcFile, which is not what is wanted

suggest:

```
'if(copyfile(argv[i], argv[argc]) == 1)'
```

then, to avoid race conditions in the writing to the output/desFile

only one process can be writing to that file at any one time.

so forking a number of processes to be writing to the same file is an error

this line:

```
'for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {'
```

needs a couple of modifications to (amongst other things)
avoid trying to copy the executable file to the desFile
and avoid trying to copy the desFile to itself

suggest:

```
'for(i = 1; i < (argc-1); i++) {'
```

Comment: `argv[]` is 0-indexed, so using your example `argc = 3` and therefore `argv[argc - 1] = argv[2] = desFile`. The rest of it makes sense. Thank you!